# LMS for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, third-party-software, learning-kit, codeplex

What is the best LMS for SharePoint? Have any one used the SharePoint learning kit from codeplex (https://slk.codeplex.com) and is it working fine for you?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this one in my organization but long time ago, my friend implemented this in his environment. During that time we find that SLK is the only best available solution(it's free) for him.

After Implementation, he was very much satisfied and used for few years until he switch his job.

SLK configuration is little pain but if you follow the steps you will be fine. check this step by step method. 
http://www.microsofttechnology.net/2012/03/sharepoint-learning-kit-2010-slk-2010.html